# Comparing performance between different sql queries which produce identical results

Tags: mysql, sql

Assuming there are 100M suppliers and 1B orders in two different tables suppliers and orders. I am trying to understand which of the queries would perform better when the data volumes are high although the results are identical. I know EXPLAIN PLAN would tell the logical plan and the cost of the query but I would like to understand which query would work faster in simple english words and why.

```
SELECT s.supplier_id
FROM suppliers s
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT o.supplier_id FROM orders o) o
    ON o.supplier_id = s.supplier_id

SELECT s.supplier_id
FROM suppliers s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM orders o WHERE o.supplier_id = s.supplier_id)

SELECT s.supplier_id 
FROM suppliers s 
WHERE s.supplier_id IN (SELECT o.supplier_id FROM orders o)

SELECT s.supplier_id
FROM suppliers s
INTERSECT
SELECT o.supplier_id
FROM orders o
```

Comment: @KeithS I don't see how it would be on-topic at Software Engineering. It also doesn't seem like a good question for Code Review as it doesn't contain much context. I don't know much about Database Administrators but I have a feeling it might not be a good fit there either.

Comment: Well, people aren't liking it here very much. Probably due to little demonstrated work.

Answer (score 0):

This might be even better than your examples:

```
SELECT s.supplier_id
FROM suppliers s
INNER JOIN orders o
    ON o.supplier_id = s.supplier_id
```

Sub queries have an inherent cost in execution, which the first three of your examples use. This cost get much higher with large datasets.

You 4th example essentially does the same as the example I provide, except it will cause a full table scan for both tables, plus a temp table to perform the intersect.

Answer (score 0):

Query 1's most likely execution plan is:

- Perform subselect on orders and store results in a table variable
- Select from suppliers, joining to subselect where found.

Optimizations include the joining behavior; SQL engines try to be really fast at joining, index or no index, because it's one of the most common operations encountered in queries. If the supplier column on orders is indexed, I'd expect this to be fastest overall. Disadvantages include the DISTINCT operator. Necessary, because of the one-to-many relationship between an order and its supplier, but the best implementation sets up a hashtable, which is linear to the numebr of orders, but adds a few layers of overhead and is very memory-inefficient, while the naive implementation is N-squared complexity which would be totally inappropriate for such large source tables.

Query 2's probable plan is:

- Select everything from suppliers
- For each supplier, index scan (or tablescan) orders until an order for that supplier is found.

This query is extremely dependent on table and data structure. If the supplier column on orders is indexed, this query will be NlogN in behavior, and the "N" in question will be the number of suppliers, not the number of orders, reducing the search space by an order of magnitude. If it's not indexed, the worst case of a supplier not having any orders requires a tablescan of 1 billion records to establish that fact, approaching N-squared complexity based on the orders table size.

Query 3's plan is:

- Perform the subselect and store the results in memory
- Perform the parent query, scanning the subselect results for each row found to filter.

Best case, the query engine simplifies this to a join on the indexed supplier column of orders. Worst-case, for each of 100m suppliers, the query engine scans up to 1 billion rows.

Query 4's plan is:

- select 100 million suppliers
- select 1 billion orders
- for each supplier, scan the orders results to find an order with the supplier.

This is flat terrible, pretty much a best-case N-squared complexity; there really isn't a good way to optimize it unless assumptions are made by the engine. Some SQL engines are better than others at making those assumptions.